# Issues with using js interop for blazor hybrid app

Tags: javascript, blazor

When I'm trying to call a js function named initMap via interop in a hybrid blazor app, I keep getting the following error:

> Could not find 'initMap' in 'window'

I have the following code:

**TestApp.Windows\wwwroot\index.html**

```
...
<head>
<script src="../js/initGoogleMap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"></script>
</head>
...
```

**TestApp.Windows\wwwroot\js\initGoogleMap.js**

```
window.initGoogleMap = {
    initMap: function () {
        const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
        const options = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options)
    }
};
```

**TestApp\WebUI\Pages\Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div id="map" style="height:500px; width:100%;"></div>

@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("first render");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initMap");
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this error occurs? I tried several small tweaks but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your path to your js has two dots and a slash. That's up a directory. It's actually in a child directory compared to where index lives. <script src="js/initGoogleMap.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Try `await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initGoogleMap.initMap");`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#capture-references-to-elements

Comment: Please also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the static files are not copied in the working directory. Here are some steps to deal with the issue:

1. In the common project make sure all static resources are set to
   "copy if newer" (in the file's properties)
2. In index.html file, please set the file path to match the following pattern:

   ```
   "_content/<PROJECT_NAME>/path/to/the/file.js"
   ```

In your case that would be:

```
"_content/TestApp/js/initGoogleMap.js"
```

3. Delete all bin and obj folders in every project and rebuild whole solution.
4. If issue persists for Android, please Uninstall the app from the android emulator and repeat step 3.

P.S. Here's a link to the issue in Blazor Binding's repo: https://github.com/dotnet/MobileBlazorBindings/issues/211